# Command line option to open program as administrator in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, command-line

If I want to open [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and edit the [`hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file, I have to invoke the Start menu, find the Notepad shortcut, right click and run as administrator, then open the `hosts` file in Notepad in order to edit.

Is there a way to use the command line to open Notepad as administrator? Something like press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `notepad /admin`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it a little bit faster by pressing `Win`, type in Search `notepad` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Or you can keep a command-prompt window open with higher privileges all the time and if some program needs to be opened with elevated privileges just start it from there with for instance: `start notepad`.

Comment: Appreciated! It's strange that `runas /env /user:DOMAIN\ADMINNAME "notepad hosts"` asks for the admin password, but when saving it still does not have enough permissions. Your `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` solution seems to give the right access: it worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `runas /?` in command prompt.

Comment: This is not much of an answer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen When you run that help command (`runas /?`) they provide this example: `runas /env /user:DOMAIN\ADMINNAME "notepad hosts"` which opens the hosts file, but it still fails to grant write permissions...

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the run command line
- Type `notepad C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

I believe this should open your `hosts` file in Notepad as an adminstrative user. It does for me anyway.

Comment: That's not correct, the notepad is not run as administrator.